# Storing image to HDPI folder of a android application remotely

Tags: android, image, web-services, android-layout, hdpi

Is it possible to store image , from server to a android application HDPI folder? If possible how can we do that?

Comment: No, the contents of an apk itself are read-only at runtime, however the application can create files within its private storage area.

Comment: Okay then what should I do update images in my app, whenever I have some updation in my data?

Comment: Either release a new apk, a new expansion package, or build in functionality to allow locally downloaded files to supersede bundled ones.

Comment: I cant get your second choice..can you please brief it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html but it looks like you can't change those without changing the apk too, so probably not what you want.  So that leaves building your own mechanism to download files from your own server and use them in place of versions from the apk.